# WSO2 ESB Sending File trough HTTP api resolves in no response

Tags: http, wso2, esb

**NOTE: im pretty new to wso2 esb, if this Question is duplicated please mark it and post the original Question.**

I want just to let the wso esb parse the content of the request to the endpoint(http). But on sending, im getting no response from the esb.
**The way is API->InSequence->HttpEndpoint.**

the log doesnt say anything.

What am i doing wrong?
The Sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="fileupload" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<log level="full"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="POST" uri-template="ĥttp://192.168.5.33/index.php?_q=get&amp;file=true">
            <timeout>
                <duration>5000</duration>
                <responseAction>discard</responseAction>
            </timeout>
        </http>
        <property name="enctype" scope="axis2" value="multipart/form-data"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<respond/>
```

Regards Liz3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution pretty simple, the best way is to use the proxy system, because it can handle files.